# Encrypt AES in PHP, decrypt in C#

Tags: c#, php, cryptography

I tried to encrypt data using this function in PHP and decrypt it with the other function in C#. But I don't get the same string.

```
//php function
    public function onCrypt($text)
    {   
    $key=md5('DFDFDFDFDFDFDFDFDFDFDFDF',true);

    $crypttext = urldecode(trim(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128,$key, $text, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND))));

    $text_crp =base64_encode($crypttext);


    return $text_crp;
            }
```

//c# function

//public static void  DecryptFile
  Parameters : 
     strKey : the key choosed in decryption .
     PathPlainTextFile : path of the crypted file 
     PathPlainTextFile : the original file decrypted.

```
public static void DecryptFile(string strKey, string pathPlainTextFile, string pathCypheredTextFile)     
  {  

//crypt key with md5 function           
System.Security.Cryptography.MD5 alg = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create();
System.Text.UTF8Encoding enc = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
byte[] md5val = alg.ComputeHash(enc.GetBytes(strKey));


StreamReader fsPlainTextFile = File.OpenText(pathPlainTextFile);    
FileInfo t = new FileInfo(pathCypheredTextFile);
StreamWriter Tex =t.CreateText();
string input = null;
while ((input = fsPlainTextFile.ReadLine()) != null)
{


        byte[] cipheredData = Convert.FromBase64String(input);

           RijndaelManaged rijndaeld = new RijndaelManaged();

            // define the used mode
            rijndaeld.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;

            // create the cipher AES - Rijndael
            ICryptoTransform decryptor = rijndaeld.CreateDecryptor(md5val,null);

             // Write the ciphered data in  MemoryStream
            MemoryStream ms= new MemoryStream(cipheredData);
            CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read);

                 // Insert  the ciphered data in a byte array
               byte[] plainTextData = new byte[cipheredData.Length];

            int decryptedByteCount = cs.Read(plainTextData, 0, plainTextData.Length);

            ms.Close();
            cs.Close();


   // Insert  the ciphered data in string encoded on Base64         
Tex.WriteLine (Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plainTextData, 0, decryptedByteCount));





}

Tex.Close();    


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a quick glance, you're not supplying an IV to the C# decryptor:

```
ICryptoTransform decryptor = rijndaeld.CreateDecryptor(md5val, null);
```

I'm not familiar with php, but it looks like you created an IV when you encrypted the content.  You'll need to have that same IV to decrypt it in the C# code (you'd need the same IV to decrypt it even if you were doing the decryption through php).

Comment: rijndaeld.Padding=Padding.zero;

Comment: ECB mode does not use any IV.

Comment: This cannot be a valid answer, as ECB does not use any IV.

Comment: @AlexMaker - Hmmm....I'd delete it if I could but it won't let me delete the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

ECB mode is not secure.  You should use either CTR mode or CBC mode.  It is also best to explicitly specify the padding you are going to use at both ends.

Comment: but i not want save  the vector IV in Data Base

Comment: CTR mode does not need an IV, just a nonce, which can be smaller.